# "In the world" or "across the world"?

Tags: grammar

I am confused when to use 'in' and 'across' when I am saying something like

> This food is *the* most expensive **in** the world.

or

> Japan has the biggest aquarium **in** the world.

I think "in the world" is correct for the sentences I wrote. But when should I use "across"? Would the sentence still be correct if I said

> Japan has the biggest aquarium **across** the world?

Comment: Do you want the last sentence in your question to have *in the world* or *across the world*?

Answer (score 3):

If you are making a comparison (which includes superlatives), "in" refers to the population from which you are making the comparison.  The biggest X **in** Y refers to the biggest X of the examples found in Y.

"Across" refers to dispersion; [M-W defines it as meaning "throughout".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/across)  For example, French-speaking people "across" Europe refers to French-speaking people wherever they might be throughout Europe.

So to your examples, you might say, "This food is the most expensive in the world" (correct), or "This food has become expensive across Asia", meaning throughout Asia.  When you talk about "across the world", the term "worldwide" is more typically used.

"Japan has the biggest aquarium in the world" would be at least grammatically correct.  "Aquariums have become popular across the world" or more idiomatic,  "Aquariums have become popular worldwide" would be an example of usage for "across".

Comment: Great answer, everyone seem to always forget about **worldwide**, I know I do sometimes. What can you say about **all over the ...** and **anywhere/everywhere in the ...**?

Comment: @SovereignSun, thanks.  Thinking about these terms for this usage, they seem to be pretty interchangeable to me--across, throughout, all over, anywhere/everywhere in.  There is probably some nuance of difference, but they convey essentially the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> Japan has the biggest aquarium **in** the world.

is the correct sentence, if you wanted to use *across*, you might say

> If you search *across* the world, you will find Japan has the biggest aquarium.

Usually for superlatives

> **in** the world

is used.

> He is the fastest **in** the world.
>   They are the tallest **in** the world.
>   London is the most expensive city **in** the world.

Maybe you can think of it as

> across the world

describes an *expanse*, whereas

> **in** the world

describes a location, but sometimes they can be interchanged

> Ray's pizza is the best pizza **in** NYC.
>   Ray's pizza is the best pizza **across** NYC.

Answer (score 0):

Today's events happen to provide an excellent example

> British Airways is the only airlines **in** the world, to have cancelled all of their flights **across** the  world.